# Union Query not displaying records for second query

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have the following SQL query:

```
select (case when len(GroupName) = 0 then 'Unknown' else GroupName end) as GroupName 
,PaperId,Color,Duplex, sum(Page_Printed) As A3PagesPrinted, sum(Cost) as A3TotalCost 
from printstat where paperid = 8 and color = 0 and duplex = 0 
and Date_Print >= '2013-01-01' and Date_Print < '2013-10-21'
group by GroupName, PaperId, Color, Duplex

union all

select (case when len(GroupName) = 0 then 'Unknown' else GroupName end) as GroupName
,PaperId,Color,Duplex, sum(Page_Printed) As A3DuplexPagesPrinted, 
sum(Cost) as A3DuplexTotalCost from printstat where paperid = 8 and color = 0 
and duplex = 1 and Date_Print >= '2013-01-01' and Date_Print < '2013-10-21'
group by GroupName, PaperId, Color, Duplex
```

Now both the queries return values when run individually. But when I execute them together my record for the second query is displayed `A3DuplexPagesPrinted` and `A3DuplexTotalCost`.

Why is that?

Comment: nothing is different apart from conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UNION` query will take the column names from the first part of the query, and fill all subsequent parts into those columns in the same order, *regardless of names or aliases*.

Therefore your fifth and sixth column from the second part (you give them aliases `A3DuplexPagesPrinted` and `A3DuplexTotalCost`) will be filled into the fifth and sixth columns of the result and named `A3PagesPrinted` and `A3TotalCost` (the aliases from the first SELECT clause).

If you want to differentiate the columns in the two queries, you will have to specify *all* columns for each part of the query (note the NULLs below):

```
select case when len(GroupName) = 0 then 'Unknown' else GroupName end as GroupName,
    PaperId,
    Color,
    Duplex, 
    sum(Page_Printed) As A3PagesPrinted, 
    sum(Cost) as A3TotalCost,
    NULL AS A3DuplexPagesPrinted,
    NULL AS A3DuplexTotalCost
from printstat where paperid = 8 and color = 0 and duplex = 0 
and Date_Print >= '2013-01-01' and Date_Print < '2013-10-21'
group by GroupName, PaperId, Color, Duplex

union all

select case when len(GroupName) = 0 then 'Unknown' else GroupName end as GroupName,
    PaperId,
    Color,
    Duplex,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    sum(Page_Printed) As A3DuplexPagesPrinted, 
    sum(Cost) as A3DuplexTotalCost
from printstat where paperid = 8 and color = 0 
and duplex = 1 and Date_Print >= '2013-01-01' and Date_Print < '2013-10-21'
group by GroupName, PaperId, Color, Duplex
```

Comment: actually my table does not contain `A3PagesPrinted` `A3TotalCost` `A3DuplexPagesPrinted` `A3DuplexTotalCost` columns. these are user defined columns based on the conditions defined in the `where` clause.

Comment: That's fine, but if you want the data separated out, you'll have to specify all columns across. (I'm assuming this is dynamically generated SQL now)